# Dynamic update of chart-series using a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-charts

I am trying to update charts using VBA.

I have a timeseries that I update ad-hoc. I wish to update the chart using VBA. When I get to the chartobjects it errors.

Both the chart and the series have names:

```vb
Dim tsEURLengde As Integer
Dim rngEUR As Range

tsEURLengde = Range("A2").Value 'A2 is count of rows containing chartdata

Set rngEUR = cnGrafer.Range("B5", cnGrafer.Range("b5").Offset(tsEURLengde)) 'cnGrafer is the ws codename
cnGrafer.ChartObjects("chSpreader").SeriesCollection("Bank 2 5y").Values = cnGrafer.Range("B5", cnGrafer.Range("b5").Offset(tsEURLengde))
```

The error message is:

> "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Try `.Values = "'" & cnGrafer.Name & "'!" & cnGrafer.Range("B5", cnGrafer.Range("b5").Offset(tsEURLengde)).Address`

Comment: thanks. I did it but got the same error 

code:
cnGrafer.ChartObjects("chSpreader").SeriesCollection("Bank 2 5y").Values = "'" & cnGrafer.Name & "'!" & cnGrafer.Range("B5", cnGrafer.Range("b5").Offset(tsEURLengde)).Address

can it be a References issue?

Comment: `.ChartObjects("chSpreader").Chart.SeriesCollection` IIRC ... add the `.Chart` in before `SeriesCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- It is [`Chart.SeriesCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.seriescollection), not `ChartObject.SeriesCollection`.

```
.ChartObjects("chSpreader").Chart.SeriesCollection...
```

- Rather than assign the `Range`, assign its `.Address`, including the sheet name:

```
With cnGrafer
   Dim s As String
   s = "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("B5",.Range("b5").Offset(tsEURLengde)).Address

   .ChartObjects("chSpreader").Chart.SeriesCollection("Bank 2 5y").Values = s
End With
```